# Click button and windows confirmation to update query and redirect page

Tags: php, mysql, ajax

i have problem with redirect page and query update. If i clicked button, there is an windows confirmation, if i click yes, i call ajax to send data to my php page, and my php page do a query. After success, i want redirect to another page. This is my html code

```
$(document).on("click", "#tombolvalidasi", function() {
        var pil = <?php echo $_GET['pilih']; ?>;
        var r = confirm("Validasi Pesanan?");
        if (r == true) 
        {
            $.ajax({
                    type: "GET",
                    url: host+'/skripsi3/web/validasipesan.php',
                    data: { "id": pil},
                    success: function (data){
                         if (data == "success") {
                             window.location = "pesanvalid.php?pilih="+pil;
                         }

                    },
                    error: function (e) {
                        alert('Fail');
                    }
                });
        } 
        else 
        {

        }

    });
```

and this is my php code

```
<?php
session_start();
include "connectdb.php";

$idacara = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET["id"]);
$cons = "Accepted";

$query="UPDATE `preorder` SET `statuspesanan`='$cons' WHERE `id_acara`='$idacara'";
$result = mysql_query($query);
echo "success";
```

?>

Hope someone can tell me what's wrong with my code. Thank You Guys and
Have a nice day!! Cheers!!